# Convert JSON data from http body request to string in PowerShell

Tags: json, string, powershell, http

I'm building a Function App in Azure using PowerShell HTTP Trigger.
The JSON body content looks something like this:

**Input**

```json
{
    "name": "azure 0103",
    "time": 1400,
    "stages": {
        "MultiStageReviewSettings": [
            {
                "StageName": "Stage1",
                "Reviewers": [
                    "ayewrewtela@t7rfdspfdsc.onfdsmicrosoft.com"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

```bash
param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)
$label = $Request.Body.Name
$time = $Request.Body.Time
$stages = $Request.Body.Time
```

I need to covert the stages object to a single line string and it has to be like this:

**Output**

```bash
$stringData = '{ "MultiStageReviewSettings": [ { "StageName": "Stage1", "Reviewers": [ "ayewrewtela@t7rfdspfdsc.onfdsmicrosoft.com" ] } ] }'
```

Comment: I believe you're looking for `ConvertTo-Json -Compress`

Comment: I tried ConvertTo-Json -Compress but it doesn't return a string I believe so it was not working when invoking the next method. When I use the hardcoded Output that I shared in the question it works fine.

Comment: something like this ? $stages = ConvertFrom-Json | ConvertTo-Json $Request.Body.stages -Compress

Comment: assuming `$Request.Body.stages` is already an object, then more like this: `$stages = $Request.Body.stages | ConvertTo-Json -Compress -Depth 99` should work properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by [Santiago](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) the way to do it is :

```bash
$stages = $Request.Body.stages | ConvertTo-Json -Compress -Depth 99
```